# What Hypervisor/GPU can be used for gaming under a virtualized environment?

Tags: virtualization, vt-d

My motherboard is the "Z68 Extreme7 Gen3", and it supports VT-d. I also have an i3, that also supports VT-d.

I would like to play games under a virtualized environment using graphics card passthrough. What Hypervisor and GPU support this?

Is this even possible?

Comment: Probably, Xen - take a look at [this Phoronix post](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTA3NjA)

Comment: Keep in mind, you can't passthrough a device if the VM host is using it.  You'll probably need a separate graphics card for the host.

Comment: Thanks both. I've purchased a 7970 and i will post the results :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it was rather easy to make it work.

```
Ubuntu 12.04 + Xen 4.1
ASRock Z68 Extreme7 Gen3
Intel i5-2500 (not the K version)
AMD 7970 Gh Edition
```

[image]

ATI seems to be the only viable solution while Xen-dev 4.2 is working on something for Nvidia, but they are still in alpha stage. They implement a pack that makes Nvidia cards working a little bit and they break AMD support. Tragicomic.

Comment: How does this work in practice? Can you switch between Ubuntu and Windows? Are they using the same graphics card and monitors?

Comment: Ubuntu is the hypervisor and dosen't have a graphic device. It's a server on the rooftop. For do what you want to, you should use the (mainboard) gpu for ubuntu, and the radeon for windows.

Comment: @cedivad: I have one doubt is the graphics card also virtual in your experiment?

Comment: No, it's real, in every sense.